# Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, chrome, certificates

When trying to update Google Chrome the following error message appears:

> Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The
> certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the
> certificate verification.

[image]

I tried using the command below, but it still shows the error.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org
```

Comment: Unless you tell us who the issuer is, then there is very little we can do. However, a typical reason would be your ISP is acting as a proxy, otherwise known as a MIM attack.

Comment: This part of your command looks like it's missing important punctuation in the middle:  '**ca-certificatessudo mkdir**'